# Proof to show Sequence is Cauchy correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Given the two facts

1. The sequence $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy in the $L^2(D)$ norm.
2. For each $x$ we can apply the following inequality $\|x\|_{E(D)} \leq k \|x\|_{L^2(D)}$ where $k > 0$

I want to show that $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy in the $E(D)$ norm as well. Here is my attempt.

Since $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy in the $L^2(D)$ norm, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all natural numbers $m,n >N$ we have

$\|x_m -x_n\|_{L^2(D)}< \varepsilon$

Then using fact (2) we get

$\|x_m -x_n\|_{E(D)}< k \|x_m -x_n\|_{L^2(D)}< k \varepsilon$

Take $\varepsilon_{new} = k \varepsilon$ then this completes the proof that $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy in the $E(D)$ norm as well.

Does this work?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: @joriki oo thanks! Didn't realize that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Your proof works provided you restate condition 2 to drop the "n" subscript. Otherwise the inequality only applies to the elements of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, and there is no guarantee that the differences between the elements of the sequence will themselves be members of the same sequence.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oops! Didn't really mean to have the n subscript in there. I just meant is as that inequality holds for all of those elements of the sequence. I'll edit it. Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof is correct. In fact, you have proven: if $T:X\to Y$ is linear and continuous and $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C$ then $(Tx_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!